# How to merge 2 trained model in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tf.keras, keras-layer

Good evening everyone,

I have 5 classes and each one has 2000 images, I built 2 Models with different model names and that's my model code

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                       input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
], name="Model1")

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                    batch_size=128, epochs=30, validation_split=0.2)

model.save('f3_1st_model_seg.h5')


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
], name="Model2")

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                    batch_size=128, epochs=30, validation_split=0.2)

model.save('f3_2nd_model_seg.h5')
```

then I used this code to merge the 2 models

```
input_shape = [150, 150, 3]

model = keras.models.load_model('1st_model_seg.h5')
model.summary()

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       

 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 74, 74, 32)       0
 )

 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248      

 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 36, 36, 32)       0
 2D)

 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496     

 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 17, 17, 64)       0
 2D)

 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 128)       73856

 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 7, 7, 128)        0
 2D)

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 6272)              0

 dense (Dense)               (None, 5)                 31365

=================================================================
Total params: 133,861
Trainable params: 133,861
Non-trainable params: 0

model2 = keras.models.load_model('2nd_model_seg.h5')
model2.summary()

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 148, 148, 32)      896

 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 74, 74, 32)       0
 )

 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248

 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 36, 36, 32)       0
 2D)

 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496

 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 17, 17, 64)       0
 2D)

 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 128)       73856

 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 7, 7, 128)        0
 2D)

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 6272)              0

 dense (Dense)               (None, 5)                 31365

=================================================================
Total params: 133,861
Trainable params: 133,861
Non-trainable params: 0


def concat_horizontal(models, input_shape):
    models_count = len(models)
    hidden = []
    input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    for i in range(models_count):
        hidden.append(models[i](input))
    output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(hidden)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    return model


new_model = concat_horizontal(
    [model, model2], (input_shape))
new_model.save('f1_1st_merged_seg.h5')
new_model.summary()

 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 150, 150, 3  0           []
                                )]

 model1 (Sequential)            (None, 5)            133861      ['input_1[0][0]']

 model2 (Sequential)            (None, 5)            133861      ['input_1[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 10)           0           ['model1[0][0]',
                                                                  'model2[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 267,722
Trainable params: 267,722
Non-trainable params: 0
```

so after I tested the merged model I found some images getting classes 7 and 9 although I have only 5 classes and that's my code for prediction

```
class_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', D', 'E']

for img in os.listdir(path):
    # predicting images
    img2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
        os.path.join(path, img), target_size=(150, 150))
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img2)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    images = np.vstack([x])
    classes = np.argmax(model.predict(images), axis=-1)
    y_out = class_names[classes[0]]
```

I got this error

y_out = class_names[classes[0]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It looks like you're trying to concatenate two models when you need to concatenate outputs. I'm also pretty sure you can't really concatenate sequential outputs using `concatenate()` because it would be tensors and not layers. You need the `Functional API` if you want to combine two models like that. Sequential does not train two submodels in that way, but it could be used to train sequential (as in, one after the other) models.

Comment: @djinn sorry i'm beginner so that merge is wrong? So if i have 60,000 images how to train that in one model because I got illocated memory size something like that:(

Answer (score 0):

for this case it could have been done even by sequential method, look you are trying to concatenate two output layers with 5 columns; so it would lead into increase classes from 5 to 10; try out to define these two models up to output layer (the flatten layer as the last layer defined for both these models) and then define final model with input layer, these two models, and concatenate layer and then the output layer with five units and activation;

so remove output layer

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

from those two models, and implement it just as one layer after the output layer you have defined here

```
def concat_horizontal(models, input_shape):
    models_count = len(models)
    hidden = []
    input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    for i in range(models_count):
        hidden.append(models[i](input))
    output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(hidden)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(output)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    return model
```

But notice it would be better to define  branch models based on functional API method for these cases

Comment: Thanks, bro for your comment I will try your code, sorry I didn't understand what is "define branch models based on functional API method" means.

Comment: by the sequential method its only possible to create network architecture as stacks of layers (sequence of layers) but by the functional API its possible to create models with parallel layers and even multuple inputs and outputs, even you could create wide and deep models, something like as residual network which, these type of models are called branch models.

Comment: It didn't work when I removed that Line tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax) when I was testing the model it gave me all the images the class 0 , can you give me link to learn about branch models.?

Comment: beg your pardon! look the functional API is as same as  the structure you have been used to define the last model, instead of creating model with seuqnces of layers in a list, you would define input layer and then each layer will be applied on the output of the previous layer; but for more details refer to this link, even you would rewrite the last model code easier; https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#use-the-same-graph-of-layers-to-define-multiple-models